# javascript cannot access array items

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a global var: `var url_device = [];`
And a function that populate it.

```
request.onload = function () { //function pour les devices
    // Begin accessing JSON data here
    var valu = JSON.parse(this.response);

    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        for (var i = 0; i < valu.data.length; i++) {
           var namespace = valu.data[i].namespace;
           var idd = valu.data[i].id;
           url_device.push(url_data + namespace + idd);
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            request_data.open('GET', url_device[j], true);
            request_data.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json')
            request_data.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
            request_data.setRequestHeader('X-API-KEY', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
            request_data.send();
            request_data.onload = function () { //function pour les data des devices
                var valu_d = JSON.parse(this.response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Normally, url_device contains 2 items after my first request:

```
[] ​ 0: "https://url/api/v0/data/streams/apple1841" ​ 
    1: "https://url/api/v0/data/streams/device19999" ​ 
length: 2 ​
__proto__: Array []
```

But I cannot access these items. That's why my second request, in the j loop doesn't work. I would like to GET data from the first url (item[0]), and the second one.

Comment: Please format your code properly. You have strange indentation and missing closing brackets.

Comment: if you declare `var request_data = new XMLHttpRequest();`, isn't it better? It's maybe the request that doesn't work. Maybe it's all ok with the array - have you debugged url_device[j] value?

Comment: It works now. I just add another loop after my request_data.send.